# Is there a preferred way to store a user's preferences in a CakePHP application?

Tags: php, cakephp, settings, preferences

I was wondering if there is a widely accepted way to store a user's preferences in a CakePHP application. For example, some ways I can think of are:

1. Having individual settings in the user model as fields.
2. Having a preferences table with a key and value field.
3. Having a preferences table with one entry per user and preferences as fields. (Similar to the first, I suppose)

Is there a way that might be better for an application that might change or expand (i.e. one that may account for preferences to be added or removed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the [KeyvalueBehavior](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/Model/Behavior/KeyvalueBehavior.php) in CakeDC's [Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/) as a starting point.

Extract the plugin to `Plugin/Utils/` and create a database table called `preferences` with the following fields: `user_id`, `field`, `value`

```
<?php
class Preference extends AppModel {

    $actsAs = array('Utils.Keyvalue');

}
```

You can then save and retrieve preferences like so (assuming `User hasMany Preferences`):

```
$this->User->Preference->saveSection($this->Auth->user('id'), array(
    'Preference' => array(
        'dob' => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        'gender' => 'm|f|n',
        'url' => 'http://www.example.com',
    )
), 'Profile');

$this->User->Preference->getSection($this->Auth->user('id'), 'Profile');
```

Comment: I suppose this is similar to my #2 but it would probably be simpler to use this plugin instead of managing all the preferences myself. I'm just thinking about the number of preferences I would need and the ridiculous number of rows this would take up for just a few users. I'm wondering if it might not be easier to have one row of preferences per user instead. The advantage to key/value rows would be not needing to change the table structure if a preference is to be added but I like the idea of having a field for each preference with a non-null value so I have a solid value for each one.

Comment: Yup, this is approach #2. Largely the decision is up to you as to how flexible the preference fields need to be.

Comment: I haven't decided yet but I'll accept this as the answer because you gave me a very valid alternative to what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add or remove preference on web interface (not changing db schema), then you'll need the 2nd option (EAV model). The downside is, the queries are gonna be pretty complicated.

But if the preference changes are rare, do the 3rd one.

Answer (score -2):

You could also consider storing User dependent, non critical information in a Cookie. With a long lifetime, this could be sufficient.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking more along the lines of information that isn't related to the user themselves, but more like that user's preferences for interacting with an application (e.g. notification preferences)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant... probably suits perfectly for storing in a Cookie, like statusses of hideable boxes, favorite options/links, etc

Comment: I know this is old, but this is a terrible suggestion. This way the user preferences would only be stored on that particular browser. If a user logs in elsewhere or clears their cookies their preferences (e.g. opting out of emails) would be lost.